# Simulate Python Install in Windows Registry

Tags: windows, python-2.7, registry

I'm developing a Python 2.7 based application that will be distributed to Windows machines using Pyinstaller. The application uses a third party API.

I can satisfy all the API's dependency requirements. It doesn't need Python 2.7 to be installed on the host machine.

However, the API crashes unless it can find these Windows registry keys that are normally set by the Windows Python 2.7 msi installer:

```
[HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Python]

[HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Python\Pythoncore\2.7]

[HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Python\Pythoncore\2.7\InstallPath]
@="C:\\python27"

[HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Python\Pythoncore\2.7\PythonPath]
@="C:\\python27;C:\\python27\\Lib\\;C:\\python27\\DLLs\\"
```

I can make the API crash or run at will by removing or adding the above to the registry.

I tested that setting these keys by hand has no ill effect on either a future installation of Python 2.7 or on Windows Add/Remove programs feature.

I know little about Windows registry. Is there a potential for harm to end users' OS if my application writes these keys on hosts that lack Python 2.7?

Comment: Sideeffect: https://pythonclock.org/

Comment: Just out of curiosity: How are you running python code without a python env? And how can you guarantee that _all_ code paths of the 3rd party API is statisfied by your code?

Comment: The code is frozen and self contained in a Pyinstaller .exe build. It doesn't require Python on the host. I can not guarantee anything regarding this poorly documented API. It's been all trial-and-error making it work.